# ASSIMP library imports wrong number of bones from COLLADA file

Tags: opengl, assimp

I have a COLLADA(.dae) file exported from Blender, also I have program that read all data from structure generated with Assimp and I want to translate all data in more readable format. Problem appears when I want to read aiBone structure from aiMesh from aiNode from aiScene: my program shows wrong number of bones. 
It's only a simple figure with few bones, without animation.
I don't know where is problem. In my program logic or Assimp or Blender...

- Assimp 3.3.1
- OpenGL 4.0.
- Blender 2.78c

My code

```
void start(){
    Importer importer;
    unsigned int flags = 0;// aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_GenNormals | aiProcess_FlipUVs;
    const aiScene* scene = importer.ReadFile(filePath, flags);
    if (!scene || scene->mFlags&& AI_SCENE_FLAGS_INCOMPLETE || !scene->mRootNode) {
        cout << "Model::'" << filePath << "':" << importer.GetErrorString() << endl;
        system("pause");
        return;
    }
    cout << "Model loaded" << endl;
    showHierarchy(scene, scene->mRootNode);
}

void showHierarchy(const aiScene* scene, aiNode* currNode) {
        string boneName = currNode->mName.C_Str();
        aiNode* parent = currNode->mParent;
        string parentName = parent == NULL ? "NO ROOT" : parent->mName.C_Str();

        unsigned int* meshesIndexes = currNode->mMeshes;
        cout << "Num. meshes: " << currNode->mNumMeshes << endl;

        for (int nrMesh = 0; nrMesh < currNode->mNumMeshes; ++nrMesh) {
            aiMesh* mesh = scene->mMeshes[meshesIndexes[nrMesh]];
            if (mesh->mNumBones > 0) {
                cout << "Num. bones: " << mesh->mNumBones << endl;
                aiBone** bones = mesh->mBones;
                for (int nrBone = 0; nrBone < mesh->mNumBones; ++nrBone) {
                    aiBone* bone = bones[nrBone];                   
                    cout << "Bone "<<nrBone<<": " << bone->mName.C_Str() << endl;
                }
            }
        }

        //for each child do the same operations
        for (int nrChild = 0; nrChild < currNode->mNumChildren; ++nrChild) {
            showHierarchy(scene, currNode->mChildren[nrChild]);
        }
}
```

Maybe will help

```
<node id="Armature" name="Armature" type="NODE">
        <translate sid="location">-1.290625 0.08518557 -3.139279</translate>
        <rotate sid="rotationZ">0 0 1 0</rotate>
        <rotate sid="rotationY">0 1 0 0</rotate>
        <rotate sid="rotationX">1 0 0 0</rotate>
        <scale sid="scale">2.297401 2.297401 2.297401</scale>
        <node id="Bone" name="Bone" sid="Bone" type="JOINT">
          <matrix sid="transform">1 0 2.38419e-7 0.5586469 2.38419e-7 0 -1 -0.01256594 0 1 0 0.9420496 0 0 0 1</matrix>
          <node id="Bone_001" name="Bone.001" sid="Bone_001" type="JOINT">
            <matrix sid="transform">1 6.41312e-9 -7.15169e-7 0 1.28262e-8 0.9996382 0.02689855 0.48549 7.15083e-7 -0.02689855 0.9996381 0 0 0 0 1</matrix>
            <node id="Bone_002" name="Bone.002" sid="Bone_002" type="JOINT">
              <matrix sid="transform">1 -3.70967e-8 2.378e-7 0 1.85446e-8 0.9997111 0.02403316 0.3515059 -2.38796e-7 -0.02403316 0.9997112 3.72529e-9 0 0 0 1</matrix>
              <node id="Bone_006" name="Bone.006" sid="Bone_006" type="JOINT">
                <matrix sid="transform">1 1.94806e-7 2.73368e-6 0 2.50534e-6 -0.4732692 -0.8809178 0.5466702 1.11965e-6 0.880918 -0.4732695 0 0 0 0 1</matrix>
                <node id="Bone_007" name="Bone.007" sid="Bone_007" type="JOINT">
                  <matrix sid="transform">-0.9999999 -2.50612e-6 4.84192e-6 0 3.08088e-6 0.4735363 0.8807744 0.3267682 -4.50835e-6 0.8807743 -0.4735363 0 0 0 0 1</matrix>
                  <node id="Bone_008" name="Bone.008" sid="Bone_008" type="JOINT">
                    <matrix sid="transform">1 -4.58268e-7 3.0653e-6 0 2.77133e-8 0.9891911 0.1466312 0.3368657 -3.1009e-6 -0.1466312 0.9891911 -5.96046e-8 0 0 0 1</matrix>
                    <extra>
                      <technique profile="blender">
                        <connect>1</connect>
                        <layer>0</layer>
                        <roll>3.141592</roll>
                        <tip_x>0</tip_x>
                        <tip_y>0.0444796</tip_y>
                        <tip_z>-0.4622855</tip_z>
                      </technique>
                    </extra>
                  </node>
                  <extra>
                    <technique profile="blender">
                      <connect>1</connect>
                      <layer>0</layer>
                      <roll>-3.141596</roll>
                    </technique>
                  </extra>
                </node>
                <extra>
                  <technique profile="blender">
                    <connect>1</connect>
                    <layer>0</layer>
                    <roll>2.86102e-6</roll>
                  </technique>
                </extra>
              </node>
              <node id="Bone_003" name="Bone.003" sid="Bone_003" type="JOINT">
                <matrix sid="transform">1 -2.14772e-7 -9.97458e-8 0 -1.29403e-8 -0.4887015 0.8724509 0.5466702 -2.38636e-7 -0.872451 -0.4887016 0 0 0 0 1</matrix>
                <node id="Bone_004" name="Bone.004" sid="Bone_004" type="JOINT">
                  <matrix sid="transform">1 -2.70245e-8 -2.22184e-7 0 1.97028e-7 0.6096119 0.7927001 0.2557451 1.34571e-7 -0.7927002 0.6096118 0 0 0 0 1</matrix>
                  <node id="Bone_005" name="Bone.005" sid="Bone_005" type="JOINT">
                    <matrix sid="transform">1 -3.3895e-8 -4.78732e-7 0 1.69833e-7 0.9634752 0.2677974 0.4389689 4.5297e-7 -0.2677974 0.9634753 0 0 0 0 1</matrix>
                    <extra>
                      <technique profile="blender">
                        <connect>1</connect>
                        <layer>0</layer>
                        <roll>-7.15256e-7</roll>
                        <tip_x>0</tip_x>
                        <tip_y>-0.08205157</tip_y>
                        <tip_z>-0.4585228</tip_z>
                      </technique>
                    </extra>
                  </node>
                  <extra>
                    <technique profile="blender">
                      <connect>1</connect>
                      <layer>0</layer>
                      <roll>-2.38419e-7</roll>
                    </technique>
                  </extra>
                </node>
                <extra>
                  <technique profile="blender">
                    <connect>1</connect>
                    <layer>0</layer>
                  </technique>
                </extra>
              </node>
              <extra>
                <technique profile="blender">
                  <connect>1</connect>
                  <layer>0</layer>
                  <roll>-2.38419e-7</roll>
                </technique>
              </extra>
            </node>
            <extra>
              <technique profile="blender">
                <connect>1</connect>
                <layer>0</layer>
                <roll>-4.76837e-7</roll>
              </technique>
            </extra>
          </node>
          <extra>
            <technique profile="blender">
              <layer>0</layer>
              <roll>2.38419e-7</roll>
            </technique>
          </extra>
        </node>
      </node>
```

Comment: Assimp has a standalone viewer. Can you compare the number of bones in the viewer with the number in Blender?

Comment: Yes. I have these bones in Blender:
Bone,
Bone.001, 
  Bone.002,
   Bone.006,
 Bone.007,
  Bone.008,
   Bone.003,
    Bone.004,
  Bone.005
 
but in program
Num. bones: 5
Bone0: Bone.003
Bone1: Bone.002
Bone2: Bone.006
Bone3: Bone.008
Bone4: Bone.004

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. Problem was in vertices. aiBone structure contain, among other things, vertices weights. My 3D model has too few weights and exists bones that don't affect vertices, so Assimp didn't loaded bones that affected 0 vertices.

Comment: Can you tell me more information about this please? Was it a problem in Blender or in the Code, and how did you fix it in Blender if it was there?

Comment: apparently my issue was the flag `aiProcess_PreTransformVertices` like explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58561457/how-to-actually-get-bone-and-animation-data-with-assimp